# Will my app be ok for the next 2 months with parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm building an iPhone application for my final year project in college. I have been using parse.com as the backend for my app but am now worried that with parse shutting down it will effect my app when I need to present it in 2 months time. I know parse says they aren't shutting down till January 28, 2017 but I'm fearful there might be a lot of down time, especially as it seems their pushing people to migrate by April 28, 2016. Can someone please give me some insight into this? Or if anyone has a way of contacting Parse so I can see if i'll be OK

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should be fine. I am also dealing with the same problem and I haven't seen anything that says that the Parse backend won't work. I believe that it is only in January that it will stop working. But that gives you plenty of time to migrate your Parse Backend or to try other options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, Parse will stay up until 2017. I personally won't worry about it too much, but if you want, you can spawn your own parse server as a backup.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform